On the spectrum of bosonic string
In Becker-Becker-Schwarz book on page 51, the author mentions that

"the total number of states at mass level $N=2$ is equal to 324 which is the dimensionality of the symmetric traceless second-rank tensor representation of $SO(25)$. So in this sense, the spectrum consists of a single massive spin-two state at this level".

I would be really grateful if someone could explain me why the spectrum consists of a single spin-two state.
The author has also mentioned on the next page that all of the massive representations can be rearranged in complete $SO(25)$ multiplets, similarly. How do I see this fact?
